# Data on press conferences from English-speaking press conferences

Tags: data-request, sports, nlp, english

I looking for open data on press conferences from English-speaking football/soccer leagues, preferably from the EPL, Champions League, or MLS but any English-speaking league would do. I need transcripts of the press conferences and game data to go with it.